# How to replace recessed halogen light from an eyeball fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I have a fused halogen bulb in this eyeball fixture. It's fairly resistant to twisting and pulling. The previous tenants managed to damage a similar fixture in another room, and I don't want to end up the same.

How do I safely replace this bulb?[image]

I'm also thinking about replacing all the halogens here with LEDs. Do I need anything other than LED bulbs that fit in the same socket? I remember seeing something about mains adapters for the LEDs. Are these necessary?

Comment: There are LED bulbs which have their own "adapter" (power supply) to run off mains directly. The hard question is going to be whether any are available in a size and connector type which will fit that fixture. I had to do a lot of searching to find chandalier-base bulbs that threw enough light to be useful, and those are bulkier than the bulb you want to replace... and need enough airflow around them to keep the circuits from overheating, which that type of fixture may not provide. So a good LED retrofit for this will probably exist eventually, but may not exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

The eyeball or gimbal fixture has spring loaded clips. SHUT OFF POWER, take utility knife and score any paint that may have sealed the ring to ceiling, pull the ring from straight down, compress and release spring tension, pull assembly out of can. By holding the socket in one hand and twist bulb with other......yes/no...safety glasses, gloves, and a bag to put over bulb and assembly and break bulb.... sometimes you can just twist the bulb until it releases from its base, the socket will now be free from gimbal assembly, I use a pair of linemen plier to free the base from the socket...yes/no replace socket....MAKE SURE POWER IS OFF FIRST

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a metal ring in the rim of the fixture that hold the light bulb in place. With a flat screwdriver you can remove that ring and then the bulb should drop out.